# Add event handler and call once immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

In a web application using jQuery, I have the following code:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function (event) {
    let isChecked = event.currentTarget.checked;
    // Do something
});
```

This will do something whenever the user clicks on a checkbox.

It is necessary to properly initialise the page state by calling this event handler once when loading the page, so it can do whatever would be done on a change of the checkbox already in the beginning.

How can I simply call the added event handler for all matching elements, without actually triggering the event? In the case of "click", this would modify the checkbox state which would break the data.

My current workaround is this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]")
    .on("click change", function (event) {
        let isChecked = event.currentTarget.checked;
        // Do something
    })
    .change();
```

This adds the event handler for multiple events and only triggers one that has no side effects. But I'd like to limit the event handlers on what's really necessary. If only a "click" event can be used on an element, there are no alternatives. Also, in my case, only elements are hidden or shown, but if something else happens, it might happen twice now.

I'm looking for the `onAndNow` function in this example pseudocode:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").onAndNow("click", function (event) {
    let isChecked = event.currentTarget.checked;
    // Do something
});
```

This is another not-so-nice and incomplete solution:

```
function onCheckboxClicked(event) {
    let isChecked = event.currentTarget.checked;
    // Do something
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", onCheckboxClicked);
onCheckboxClicked(???);
```

Comment: Your last code example is the most appropriate solution, but what element are you expecting the function to execute on when the page first loads?

Comment: All that the event handler is attached to, i.e. all that will start the action when the user interacts with them.

Comment: In which case you need to loop through them all and pass a reference of that element to the function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `$("input[type=checkbox]").each(onCheckboxClicked)` would work, would it not? Then you could access the el with `this`?

Comment: @Kobe in that case, yes.

Comment: @ygoe, where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the function on each of the elements using this code:

```js
function onCheckboxClicked(event) {
    if (event == 0) {
      console.log("onload")
    } else {
      console.log("event")
      // Do something
    }
    
    console.log($(this).prop('checked'))

}

// Event driven
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", onCheckboxClicked);

// Executed on load
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(onCheckboxClicked);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

> Note: As you can see, you won't be able to pass an event with an onload, so you will have to write code for each situation. You can, however, access the element with `$(this)`.